# What are all the possible types in an Outlook folder?

Tags: office-interop, outlook-object-model

I am trying to iterate through the Items collection of the Inbox folder of an account.  What is the class of the Item if it is a NDR message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem). You can see that object in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): select the item, click Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon.

Comment: Thanks.  What is good way to find out the class of the item?  I am now casting as each known Item type and then checking for not null.  Rather inefficient.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Check the Class property  (exposed by all OOM objects) using late binding. It is 43 (OlObjectClass.olMail) for the MailItem objects. olReport is 46.

Comment: I am using C# and Outlook PIA. Basically how do I easily find out the type of each item in the Inbox.Items collection?  Now, I cast it as MailItem, and if it is not null it is a MailItem, etc.

Comment: One more question, do MailItem, ReportItem, etc, all those possible in the Items collection of Inbox, inherit from some base class (other than object)?

Comment: No, MailItem and ReportItem do not share a common ancestor. You will need to use late bringing (reflection) to read the Class property exposed by both.

Comment: Thanks.  By using GetType().InvokeMember I am able to Move any item to another folder.  Am assuming every type has a Move method though.

Comment: Yes, every item type has that method.